# Preventing YQL from URL encoding a key

Tags: urlencode, yql, url-encoding

I am wondering if it is possible to prevent YQL from URL encoding a key for a datatable?

**Example:**
The current guardian API works with IDs like this:

```
item_id = "environment/2010/oct/29/biodiversity-talks-ministers-nagoya-strategy"
```

The problem with these IDs is that they contain slashes (/) and these characters should not be URL encoded in the API call but instead stay as they are.

So If I now have this query

```
SELECT * FROM guardian.content.item WHERE item_id='environment/2010/oct/29/biodiversity-talks-ministers-nagoya-strategy'
```

while using the following `url` defintion in my datatable

```
<url>http://content.guardianapis.com/{item_id}</url>
```

then this results in this API call

`http://content.guardianapis.com/environment%2F2010%2Foct%2F29%2Fbiodiversity-talks-ministers-nagoya-strategy?format=xml&order-by=newest&show-fields=all`

Instead the guardian API expects the call to look like this:

`http://content.guardianapis.com/environment/2010/oct/29/biodiversity-talks-ministers-nagoya-strategy?format=xml&order-by=newest&show-fields=all`

So the problem is really just that the `/` characters gets encoded as `%2F` which I don't want to happen in this case.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

You can also check the full datatable I am using:

http://github.com/spier/yql-tables/blob/master/guardian/guardian.content.item.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI-template expansions in YQL (e.g. `{item_id}`) only follow the [version 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gregorio-uritemplate-03) spec. With version 4 it would be possible to simply (only slightly) change the expansion to do what you want, but alas not currently with YQL.

So, a solution.  You could bring a *very, very basic* `<execute>` block into play: one which adds the `item_id` value to the path as needed.

```
<execute><![CDATA[
    response.object = request.path(item_id).get().response;
]]></execute>
```

Finally, see the [diff against your table](https://gist.github.com/be8a5216cb4a141afc0c) (with a few other, minor tweaks to allow the above to work).

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly. +1 and accept. I have updated the YQL datatable accordingly. If anybody needs it: https://github.com/spier/yql-tables/tree/master/guardian/      Also the results can be seen directly in the YQL console: http://y.ahoo.it/YWeXQA3h